# Gradle continuous build behaves odd

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

Gradle is a magic box for me. I often don't get it and always do try and error.
I use gradle 8.1 and groovy scripts. I have this small task

```
import java.time.Instant

tasks.register('continuous-build') {
    dependsOn tasks.compileJava
    onlyIf { !compileJava.state.upToDate }
    logger.lifecycle("Job executed at " + Instant.now())
    doLast {
        def file = new File(projectDir, "build/classes/java/main/.reloadTrigger");
        file.createNewFile();
        file.setLastModified(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
        logger.lifecycle("This message is never seen")
    }
}
```

I want this task to run with --continuous-build and just touch a file if it's done compiling.

this is what I do:

**Run ./gradlew continuous-build --continuous**

```
$ ./gradlew continuous-build --continuous
Reload triggered at 2023-11-10T11:48:50.446501720Z   
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
Waiting for changes to input files... (ctrl-d to exit)
```

**Make a small change to Main.java which compiles fine**

```
modified: [...]Main.java
Change detected, executing build...
Reload triggered at 2023-11-10T11:49:02.870526619Z
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 from cache, 3 up-to-date
Waiting for changes to input files... (ctrl-d to exit)
```

After this the file timestamp is changed. That is what I want.

**Make a small change to Main.java which compiles with error**

```
modified: [...]Main.java
Change detected, executing build...   
Reload triggered at 2023-11-10T11:49:09.303034432Z    
> Task :compileJava FAILED
[...]Main.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
    publi static final String ANSWER = "42";
         ^
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.   
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org    
BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date    
Waiting for changes to input files... (ctrl-d to exit)
```

After this the file timestamp is **NOT** changed. That is what I want as it compiled with an error.

**Make a small change to Main.java which compiles fine again**

```
modified: [...]Main.java
Change detected, executing build...
Reload triggered at 2023-11-10T11:49:14.192599979Z
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
Waiting for changes to input files... (ctrl-d to exit)
```

After this the file timestamp is **NOT** changed anymore even the compilation succeeded. How can I achieve a file touch cmd if compileJava was successful.

And why is the second logging message never seen?

PS I have shortened the output a little bit to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to mention:

- `doLast` is an action to a task. It runs at the end of the task.
- Your gradle task `continuous-build` depends on the `compileJava` task via this line `dependsOn tasks.compileJava` which means that if `compileJava` task fails, i.e, compilation of Java classes fail then `doLast` task action will not be executed from your `continuous-build` task. So, that's why the file is not created/updated.
- This line `onlyIf { !compileJava.state.upToDate }` from the `continuous-build` gradle task tells that any task action will be executed only if the `compileJava` task state is changed. In simple words, if you do a code change in your Java classes, then `doLast` action will be executed from your `continuous-build` task, otherwise it will be skipped from the execution.

So, your `doLast` action depends on these two lines `dependsOn tasks.compileJava` and `onlyIf { !compileJava.state.upToDate }` completely.

To demonstrate, I have updated your gradle task a little bit to explain.

```
import java.time.Instant

tasks.register('continuous-build') {
    dependsOn tasks.compileJava
    onlyIf { !compileJava.state.upToDate }
    logger.lifecycle("Job executed at " + Instant.now())
    doLast {
        def file = new File(projectDir, "build/classes/java/main/.reloadTrigger");
        def created = file.createNewFile();
        logger.lifecycle("File created status :" + created);
        file.setLastModified(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
        logger.lifecycle("Last modified timestamp of the file: " + file.lastModified());
        logger.lifecycle("This message is never seen")
    }
}
```

**First time Execution:**

[image]

[image]

**Second time Execution (with no change in Java classes):**

`doLast` task action will not be executed as explained in the point (because of this line `onlyIf { !compileJava.state.upToDate }`).

[image]

**Third Time Execution (with the modification in a Java class):**

The `doLast` task action will be executed and this will trigger the file to be updated instead of creation although the timestamp will be changed this time.

[image]

**Fourth Time Execution (with the modification in a Java class with an error):**

The `doLast` task action will not be executed due to the compilation error in one of the Java classes detected by the `compileJava` task and the `continuous-build` task depends on `compileJava`.

[image]

**Fifth time Execution (with no error, i.e, reverted the changes)**: In this case, the **third time execution scenario** is repeated again.

[image]

Comment: Very nice explanation. so I awarded the bounty to you. But what I really wanted to know: What happens in the fifth execution when you fix the java error. I tried it again and what I missed is: If I add an error adn remove it afterwards, the compileJava is UP-TO-DATE because the build cache is kicking in as the exact same class was compiled before. If I fix the error and add some  other random stuff to the class, everything works as expected

Comment: @JanningVygen If you fix the errors in the classes, then the third time execution scenario will be repeated again.

Comment: @JanningVygen I have updated the answer with Fifth time execution as well.